# Uncaught ReferenceError: updateIngredient is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.editIngredient

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, button

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am trying to create a simple update/edit function to be able to edit ingredients that exist with the dataset. I am getting the above error when doing so.
Here is my code:

```
deleteIngredient(){
    const ingredientId = this.parentElement.dataset.id
    fetch(`${recipeUrl}/${ingredientId}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
    })
    this.parentElement.remove()
}

updateIngredient(){
    var editForm = document.getElementById("ingredient-input")
    console.log(editForm)
}

editIngredient(){
    var editForm = 
    `<form id="edit-form">
    <input type="text" id="edit-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient">
    </form>`
    this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', editForm)
    console.log(this.parentElement)
    document.getElementById('edit-form')
    editForm.addEventListener("click", updateIngredient)
}


const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
    editBtn.addEventListener("click", this.editIngredient)
    editBtn.innerText = "Edit"
    li.appendChild(editBtn)
    ingredientList.appendChild(li)
```

What am I doing wrong here? This should at least not be throwing this error. Please Help!

Edit: Updated code using onclick got rid of the error!

```
        const editForm = 
        `<form id="edit-form">
        <input type="text" id="edit-input">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient" onclick="updateIngredient">
        </form>`
        this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', editForm)
        console.log(this.parentElement)
        document.getElementById('edit-form')
        //editForm.addEventListener("click", updateIngredient)
    }
    
   updateIngredient(){
       document.querySelector("data-id")
   }

I could still use help with updateIngredient which will take the ingredient and edit it using the edit form. Any other advice would be so appreciated!

Edit 2: Still feeling a bit lost so here is my full Ingredient class and index.html file

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <title>Recipe App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Easy Recipe and Ingredient Saver</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>Instructions:</h2>
    <h3>Enter the name of your recipe below in the top form.</h3> 
    <h3>After creation add all the ingredients for that recipe separately and hit enter to save to the recipe.</h3>
    <div id="container">
        <h4>Create a Recipe:</h4>
        <form id="recipe-form">
            <input type="text" id="recipe-input">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Recipe">
        </form>
        <ul id="recipe-list">
           
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src='./src/ingredient.js'></script>
    <script src='./src/recipe.js'></script>
    <script src='./src/index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>


    class Ingredient {

    constructor(ingredient) {
        this.recipe_id = ingredient.recipe_id
        this.name = ingredient.name
        this.id = ingredient.id
    }

    static createIngredient(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const ingredientInput = e.target.children[0].value
        const ingredientList = e.target.nextElementSibling
        const recipeId = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id

        Ingredient.submitIngredient(ingredientInput, ingredientList, recipeId)

        e.target.reset()
    }

    renderIngredient(ingredientList){
        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.dataset.id = this.recipe_id
        li.innerText = this.name
        
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", this.deleteIngredient)
        deleteBtn.innerText = "X"
        li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
        ingredientList.appendChild(li)

        const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
        editBtn.addEventListener("click", this.editIngredient)
        editBtn.innerText = "Edit"
        li.appendChild(editBtn)
        ingredientList.appendChild(li)


    }
    
    static submitIngredient(ingredient, ingredientList, recipeId){
        fetch(ingredientUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: ingredient, 
                recipe_id: recipeId
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(ingredient => {
            let newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredient)
            newIngredient.renderIngredient(ingredientList)
        })
    }

    
    deleteIngredient(){
        const ingredientId = this.parentElement.dataset.id
        fetch(`${recipeUrl}/${ingredientId}`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        })
        this.parentElement.remove()
    }
   

    editIngredient(){
        const editForm = 
        `<form id="edit-form">
        <input type="text" id="edit-input">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient" onclick="updateIngredient">
        </form>`
        this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', editForm)
        console.log(this.parentElement)
        document.getElementById('edit-form')
        //editForm.addEventListener("click", updateIngredient)
    }
    
   updateIngredient(){
       const ingredientId = this.parentElement.dataset.id
       ingredientId.innerText("")
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call it from an inline action? (Use onclick="updateIngredient()" in the HTML instead of adding an event listener.)

Comment: Sure, when you set the `editForm` variable, replace `<input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient">` with `<input type="submit" value="Edit Ingredient" onclick="updateIngredient()">`. You won't need your event listener (`editForm.addEventListener("click", updateIngredient)`) then.

Comment: That worked to get rid of the error! Thank you so much! now I just need to figure out what to put into updateIngredient to make it edit the current data. Any advice for that by chance?

Comment: Where are you updating it? In the DOM?

Comment: No, on the web page and in the rails server.  On the page you can see a list of recipes and subsequent ingredients and I want to be able to edit the ingredients

Comment: Ok. Changing the webpage is easy. Just get the element that has the name of the ingredient in it and use the `innerHTML` to change the content. It's hard to say exactly what you need to do because I can not see your full code. As far as updating the server, you'll need to send a request back to the server with the changes either as `post` or `get` data for your server to the process and update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, you're truly kind. but I am still a bit lost so I posted my code for the ingredient class and my index.html. do you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: I should add that Im not as interested in updating the server as I am looking to just update the page.

Comment: Ok. I'm looking at your code. Does your input ever create a recipe? From there is it supposed to add ingredients? Are you currently testing it by manually creating things in the console?

Comment: Yes sir to all those questions. Let me post my repos below if you feel so inclined to take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/MisterAnthropy/recipe-app-frontend 
https://github.com/MisterAnthropy/recipe-app-backend

Comment: Sorry for the delay. To update the ingredient on the client's side first get the new name value from the edit input with `let newName = document.getElementById('edit-input').value;` then replace the name in the dom `event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = event.target.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(this.name, newName);`. Then change the ingreditand data `this.name = newName;`. Finnaly remove the edit form with `document.getElementById('edit-form').outerHTML = '';`. Since your techinally removing  and reading the DOM, you'll have to reassign the onclick events.

Comment: You're the best! The edit function is almost working now but one thing. When I use the function on the web page I am still seeing the original ingredient submitted and am having trouble getting rid of it. so for instance if the ingredient is 'beans' and I go to change that to 'edited', what I get is 'editedbeans'. Any Idea how to fix?

Comment: Sure. Since your putting the text into the element along with tags, you can't edit nearly as easily. I'd recommend when you create the ingredient to wrap the name in its own tag by itself, Then you can replace this line here `event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = event.target.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(this.name, newName);` with `event.target.parentElement.children[0].innerHTML = newName;` lmk how it works, If you need more info just say

Comment: Could you possibly help me out with wrapping the name in its own tag? I thought that is what I was doing when I created the 'li' in my renderIngredient function

Comment: Yes, but then you put the delete and edit buttons in with it too. What you should do is create a third element, the best choice is a div, and then add it like how you did with the two buttons before the two buttons, but after you create the list item. Then you can change the innerHTML of the div without effecting the buttons.